# embedded font displays no text (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

using flash develop. so i downloaded "source sans" font from here: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro?selection.family=Source+Sans+Pro

it has a bunch of ttf files, "bold, italic, etc" im guessing i only need one, so i copied the regular one to my src folder, renamed it to "SourceSansPro", right clicked on my src folder and add new font library. i named it "SourceSansPro". and heres my code now:

main class:

```
    package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;


    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        private var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat("SourceSansPro");
        private var text:TextField = new TextField;

        public function Main() 
        {
            text.embedFonts = true;
            text.setTextFormat(format);

            text.text = "abcdefg";

            addChild(text);

        }



    }

}
```

the font library thing:

```
/**
Suggested workflow:
- create a fontLibrary subfolder in your project (NOT in /bin or /src)
- for example: /lib/fontLibrary
- copy font files in this location
- create a FontLibrary class in the same location
- one font library can contain several font classes (duplicate embed and registration code)

FlashDevelop QuickBuild options: (just press Ctrl+F8 to compile this library)
@mxmlc -o bin/SourceSansPro.swf -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true -noplay
*/
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.Font;

    /**
     * Font library
     * @author 111
     */
    public class SourceSansPro extends Sprite 
    {
        /*
        Common unicode ranges:
        Uppercase   : U+0020,U+0041-U+005A
        Lowercase   : U+0020,U+0061-U+007A
        Numerals    : U+0030-U+0039,U+002E
        Punctuation : U+0020-U+002F,U+003A-U+0040,U+005B-U+0060,U+007B-U+007E
        Basic Latin : U+0020-U+002F,U+0030-U+0039,U+003A-U+0040,U+0041-U+005A,U+005B-U+0060,U+0061-U+007A,U+007B-U+007E
        Latin I     : U+0020,U+00A1-U+00FF,U+2000-U+206F,U+20A0-U+20CF,U+2100-U+2183
        Latin Ext. A: U+0100-U+01FF,U+2000-U+206F,U+20A0-U+20CF,U+2100-U+2183
        Latin Ext. B: U+0180-U+024F,U+2000-U+206F,U+20A0-U+20CF,U+2100-U+2183
        Greek       : U+0374-U+03F2,U+1F00-U+1FFE,U+2000-U+206f,U+20A0-U+20CF,U+2100-U+2183
        Cyrillic    : U+0400-U+04CE,U+2000-U+206F,U+20A0-U+20CF,U+2100-U+2183
        Armenian    : U+0530-U+058F,U+FB13-U+FB17
        Arabic      : U+0600-U+06FF,U+FB50-U+FDFF,U+FE70-U+FEFF
        Hebrew      : U+05B0-U+05FF,U+FB1D-U+FB4F,U+2000-U+206f,U+20A0-U+20CF,U+2100-U+2183

        About 'embedAsCFF' attribute:
        - is Flex 4 only (comment out to target Flex 2-3)
        - is 'true' by default, meaning the font is embedded for the new TextLayout engine only
        - you must set explicitely to 'false' for use in regular TextFields

        More information:
        http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f5f.html
        */


        [Embed(source="SourceSansPro.ttf"
        ,fontFamily  ='SourceSansPro'
        ,fontStyle   ='normal' // normal|italic
        ,fontWeight  ='normal' // normal|bold
        ,unicodeRange='U+0020-U+002F,U+0030-U+0039,U+003A-U+0040,U+0041-U+005A,U+005B-U+0060,U+0061-U+007A,U+007B-U+007E'
        ,embedAsCFF='false'
        )]
        public static const fontClass:Class;

        public function SourceSansPro() 
        {
            Font.registerFont(fontClass);

        }

    }

}
```

so in main, if text.embedFonts is false it will show the default font, if its true it will show up blank.

any help?

edit - new code

```
package
{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.Font;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        private var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat("libel");
        private var text:TextField = new TextField;

        public function Main() 
        {



            [Embed(source="libel.ttf"
        ,fontFamily  ='libel'
        ,fontStyle   ='normal' // normal|italic
        ,fontWeight  ='normal' // normal|bold
        ,unicodeRange='U+0020-U+002F,U+0030-U+0039,U+003A-U+0040,U+0041-U+005A,U+005B-U+0060,U+0061-U+007A,U+007B-U+007E'
        ,embedAsCFF='false'
        )]

        Font.registerFont();

            text.embedFonts = true;
            text.setTextFormat(format);

            text.text = "abcdefg";

            addChild(text);

        }



    }

}
```

Comment: You probably need to read this: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/751964 Use **[Embed]** metatag, then **Font.registerFont(...)**, then your sample test will probably work.

Comment: im sorry i dont understand what you mean by "Use [Embed] metatag, then Font.registerFont(...),"

Comment: That's why I provided you with the link. There's another one if the first wasn't explanatory enough: https://divillysausages.com/2011/02/17/as3-font-embedding-masterclass/ The **[Embed(...)]** metatag is an AS3 language entry that allows to embed an external file into the project and make its data accessible. You can embed plain text or binary file, or picture, or, in your case, the whole font. Then there are means to access the embedded font and to let the application use it to display text.

Comment: is the embed not already in my code? i read your links but i dont see what your trying to tell me. am i using embed or Font.registerFont() incorrectly?

Comment: You don't need the second class - at all. All you need is to **[Embed]** your font as the variable in the **Main** class then **Font.registerFont(...)** that class in the **Main** constructor.

Comment: okay so i added the embed thing and the font register to my main constructor, and when i run i get: Error: Metadata requires an associated definition.

Comment: Please update the question (you can **edit** it) with the actual code you have there. Do not assume I (or any other person here to help) can figure out what and how you did there.

Comment: uh okay its there now

Comment: Ok, I kind of understand your problems. I posted the script that is at least has the correct syntax for embedding and using the external fonts. The problem here is, you are treating scripting like magic. I provided you with two links, there's at least one place where you can clearly see how to use the **[Embed(...)]** metatag, also official AS3 documentation is pretty good so you shouldn't have had problems with reading up what and how **Fonts.registerFont(...)** method do. Yet you just copypasted some pieces of code without much understanding to it. P.S. Please delete the duplicate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you probably want.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.Font;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        // After the [Embed] tag you need
        // a variable definition it is linked to.
        [Embed(source="libel.ttf", fontFamily='libel')]
        private var Libel:Class;

        public function Main() 
        {
            // In order to share the font with the whole application,
            // you need to provide its class to the method.
            Font.registerFont(Libel);

            var aFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat;

            aFormat.font = "libel";
            // ... other format properties here.

            var aField:TextField = new TextField;

            // This way you will see that
            // TextField even if fonts don't render.
            aField.border = true;

            // Setting the default text format is a good idea here.
            aField.embedFonts = true;
            aField.setTextFormat(aFormat);
            aField.defaultTextFormat = aFormat;

            aField.text = "abcdefg";

            addChild(aField);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mellowm It would be nice of you to also indicate if the code sample actually helped and works as intended.

Comment: oh ya it worked and i understand how it all works now